# actionscript 2 movieclip events are not working

Tags: flash, actionscript, event-handling, listener, actionscript-2

I have an actionscript 2 movie with a movieclip that I want to act as a button inside a movieclip that acts as the tray for the button on a menu.

I want to define rollover methods, but I can't define a rollover that works for the button movieclip when the tray movieclip that contains the button also has an onrollover method defined.

```
        ---------------------------------------
        |                                      |
        |          -------------------         |
        |          |   button_mc     |         |
        |          -------------------         |
        |            tray_mc                   |
        ----------------------------------------
```

Is there anyway to overcome this?  I have tried to understand listeners, but without much joy and am not sure that even that would do the job.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, discovered the answer ten seconds later but it had me stumped for ages.

The event model seems to cascade downwards and is blocking.  The means that the tray event handler was catching the rollover event and answering it.

The solution was to put both the tray_mc and the button_mc inside a containing movie, whilst keeping the on(rollOver) handlers inside the tray_mc and the button_mc's actions.

Cheers All!